In Appium on Android WebView, switching context redirects me to an ads screen, preventing actions on the intended screen
Summary:
I’m using Appium for automation on an Android WebView. When switching to the WebView context, I'm redirected through an ads screen. Although I can see the expected screen, the focus remains on the ads, preventing me from performing actions on my intended screen. How can I resolve this issue
While running the test on an emulator or real device, the expected screen is visible, but the URL returned by getCurrentUrl is googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/production/sdk-core-v40-impl.html.
im using these methods:
private void updateContextHandles() {
    if (supportsContextSwitching) {
        contexts = ((SupportsContextSwitching) driver).getContextHandles();
    }
}

public void switchToWebViewContext() {
    updateContextHandles();
    if (supportsContextSwitching) {
        for (String context : contexts) {
            if (context.contains("WEBVIEW_com.XXXX.android")) {
                ((SupportsContextSwitching) driver).context(context);
                TestReporter.logReport(INFO, "Switched to WebView context: " + context);
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        TestReporter.logReport(INFO, "Context switching is not supported for this driver.");
    }
}

private void selectLoginWithEmailBtn() {
        elementHandler.switchToWebViewContext();
        waitForSeconds(10);
        elementHandler.click(accountLocator.getLoginWithEmailBtn());
    }

im just trying to click on the button on webview once the context is switched, it just worked twice randomly. Any suggestions on how to ensure the focus is on the correct screen after switching to the WebView context?
